# ToolTip in grid for display datetime from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip

I am using the selection page in which user select category and subcategory. then according to that selection user display some document in grid one document in one row.

There are five documents according to that selection, it display five grid row.

How can I display tooltips for these documents. I want to show that which time that document attached.

Comment: We need to know more information such as what language you are using and what you have tried so far to be able to better answer your question

Comment: Please provide some context (language, framework, environment) so question can be answered. Otherwise it have to be closed.

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
       <itemtemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title")%>' Visible="false">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="link1" runat="server"  CommandName="link" ForeColor="Blue"><%#Eval("title")%>                                                 
       </itemtemplate>     
          
           <itemstyle forecolor="Blue" font-size="Medium" />

Answer (score 0):

You can show tooltip by using `ToolTip` attribute:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title"> 
    <itemtemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ToolTip='<%#Eval("your-datetime")%>' Text='<%#Eval("title")%>' Visible="false">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="link1" runat="server" ToolTip='<%#Eval("your-datetime")%>' CommandName="link" ForeColor="Blue">      
    <%#Eval("title")%> 
    </itemtemplate> 
    <itemstyle forecolor="Blue" font-size="Medium" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```